# SSIS Programmatic Package Validate/Run Issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I've posted the same question on MSDN [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6cd447d8-21e5-44be-aee6-ad6bdcaac40f/programmatically-created-package-having-difficulties-running?forum=sqlintegrationservices] and I'm hoping someone over here might be able to help.

--- here's the question ---

I am trying to create a simple SSIS task to load data from a SQL Server table (with one int column called [num]) to an Oracle table (with one NUMBER column called [ID]) via the .NET Interop assemblies for SSIS. I can create the package and save it to a DTSX file, however when I run (either programmatically or via dtexec), it fails. I'm following the dev guide for programmatically creating packages, and when I poke around at the properties of the various objects nothing really jumps out at me.

As a secondary issue, I see there is a Package.Validate method available but I have no idea how to call it (there are arguments and return values required). When I run the package via dtexec it does validation and provides somewhat useful validation errors, so I'm hoping to be able to hook into that programatically.

The validation error I get is:

> Error: 2016-12-08 09:39:15.96    Code: 0xC004706B    Source:
>   {A8E8D1A6-3826-4222-B6DC-46008A1722DF} SSIS.Pipeline    Description:
>   "OLE DB Destination" failed validation and returned validation status
>   "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

From what I can tell online, the cause of this error is bad column mappings, however I've lifted the code more or less straight from the dev guide.

**So my two questions are:**

1. How can I troubleshoot this validation error VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA, preferably programatically?
2. How can I call Package.Validate in order to get such validation errors programatically?**

Any help is appreciated!

Full code listing (I run this in C# Interactive using Visual Studio, no exceptions are thrown, but result ends up with a value of Failure):

```
// these are just adding references to the context:
#r "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll"
#r "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll"
#r "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll"
#r "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Net.Http.dll"
#r "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll"
// the actual code:

using dtsrt = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using dtsp = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline;
using dtspw = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using refl = System.Reflection;
private string GetHresultSymbolicName(int errorCode)
{
    dtsrt.HResults hresults = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.HResults();
    return (from refl.FieldInfo fi in hresults.GetType().GetFields() where (((int)fi.GetValue(hresults)) == errorCode) select fi.Name).Single();
}

// base setup
dtsrt.Package package = new dtsrt.Package();
dtsrt.Executable e = package.Executables.Add("STOCK:PipelineTask");
dtsrt.TaskHost thMainPipe = e as dtsrt.TaskHost;
dtspw.MainPipe dataFlowTask = thMainPipe.InnerObject as dtspw.MainPipe;
dtsrt.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
dtsrt.PipelineComponentInfos componentInfos = app.PipelineComponentInfos;

// source connection
dtsrt.ConnectionManager srcConnectionManager = package.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
srcConnectionManager.Name = "Source OLEDB Connection";
srcConnectionManager.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Address=XXX; Database=Sandbox; Trusted_Connection=yes;";

// dest connection
dtsrt.ConnectionManager destConnectionManager = package.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
destConnectionManager.Name = "Destination OLEDB Connection";
destConnectionManager.ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle; Data Source=XXX;User Id=SANDBOX;Password=123456;";
// thanks: ole.OleDbDataReader rdr = ole.OleDbEnumerator.GetRootEnumerator();

// dest component
dtspw.IDTSComponentMetaData100 destComponent = dataFlowTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
destComponent.ComponentClassID = "DTSAdapter.OLEDBDestination.3";
destComponent.Instantiate();
dtspw.CManagedComponentWrapper destWrapper = destComponent.Instantiate();
destWrapper.ProvideComponentProperties();
destComponent.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManager = dtsrt.DtsConvert.GetExtendedInterface(destConnectionManager);
destComponent.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManagerID = destConnectionManager.ID;
destComponent.CustomPropertyCollection["CommandTimeout"].Value = 0; // no timeout
destComponent.CustomPropertyCollection["AccessMode"].Value = 2; // sqlcommand
destComponent.CustomPropertyCollection["SqlCommand"].Value = "select * from my_asdf";
destWrapper.AcquireConnections(null);
destWrapper.ReinitializeMetaData();
destWrapper.ReleaseConnections();

// source component
dtspw.IDTSComponentMetaData100 srcComponent = dataFlowTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
srcComponent.ComponentClassID = "DTSAdapter.OLEDBSource.3";
srcComponent.Instantiate();
dtspw.CManagedComponentWrapper srcWrapper = srcComponent.Instantiate();
srcWrapper.ProvideComponentProperties();
srcComponent.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManager = dtsrt.DtsConvert.GetExtendedInterface(srcConnectionManager);
srcComponent.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManagerID = srcConnectionManager.ID;
srcComponent.CustomPropertyCollection["CommandTimeout"].Value = 0; // no timeout
srcComponent.CustomPropertyCollection["AccessMode"].Value = 2; // sqlcommand
srcComponent.CustomPropertyCollection["SqlCommand"].Value = "select num from big_numbers2";
srcWrapper.AcquireConnections(null);
srcWrapper.ReinitializeMetaData();
srcWrapper.ReleaseConnections();

dtspw.IDTSPath100 path = dataFlowTask.PathCollection.New();
path.AttachPathAndPropagateNotifications(srcComponent.OutputCollection[0], destComponent.InputCollection[0]);

// Just one column mapping, as each table has just one column
dtspw.IDTSInput100 destInput = destComponent.InputCollection[0];
dtspw.IDTSVirtualInput100 vDestInput = destInput.GetVirtualInput();
destWrapper.SetUsageType(destInput.ID, vDestInput, vDestInput.VirtualInputColumnCollection[0].LineageID, dtspw.DTSUsageType.UT_READONLY);

// save it, run it
app.SaveToXml("D:\\myDtsx.dtsx", package, null);
dtsrt.DTSExecResult result = package.Execute(); // result = failure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think from looking at your code: In short, I think you are missing the step to make an association between input column and external column in your destination component.

For your destination component, after you assign the SqlCommand: the next three lines of code (AcquireConn, Reinit Meta and Close Conn) essentially get you the metadata of the sqlcommand from your oracle database. This metada will be the names of the columns and their associated data types. This information will then be stored in the ExternalMetadataColumn collection of your destination component. Now in the destination component, a "column-mapping" is established when a column in the ExternalMetadataColumn collection is associated to a column in the InputColumn Collection of the destination component.

In your code, you are creating the source component after you are making the metadata call on your destination component. So when the destination component's external metadata is created, it did not have any input columns to associate those external metadata columns.

Further down in your code, after you have created the source component and attached the source and destination you are calling the GetVirtualInput and then calling the SetUsageType with UT_READONLY. After you have called SetUsageType with UT_READONLY, you will have an input column available in the destination component, which you can then associate with a external metadata column.

So after calling the SetUsageType, now call the MapInputColumn method on the destination's design time component and pass in the id's of the input, input column and external metadata column you want to match.

So assuming that you want to map the "num" column from your source component to an external column called "my_external_column", then you woudl do this:

```
IDTSInputColumn100 inputColumn = destInputCols.InputColumnCollection["num"];

IDTSExternalMetadataColumn100 externalColumn = destInput.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection["my_external_column"];

destWrapper.MapInputColumn(destInput.ID, inputColumn.ID, externalColumn.ID)
```

You should be able to see a column being mapped "correctly". For the mapping to succeed, the data types (specifically the SSIS data types) should match.

Comment: In the first line of code, I assume you mean destInput.InputColumnCollection? Because that definitely worked! I'm marking this the answer, but if you could expand on how you learned this I'd appreciate it. I've read through the docs on MSDN and either they are sparse and hard to grasp or I'm being dense and I really like to know which!

Comment: Yes..in the first line of code, it shud be the destInput.

Comment: As far as learning, it was mostly by going through the documentation, coding it and observing the changes in the xml of the dtsx. Pretty soon you will observe that all Pipeline components (whether it is a lookup or a merge or source etc.)follow the same design principles of being configured. Am putting together some notes on this and will let you know. Meanwhile, let know if you have any other ssis programmatic questions.

Comment: I've been resorting to diffing xml from "known good" packages I make in BIDS to my programatic ones... good to know I'm not missing out on any magic :P  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the .dtsx file in a text editor and review the metadata information in the package? Anything stand out there?

My suspicion is that the "Select *" in the SQL Server query is not being interpreted as the correct data type. The error wouldn't show up until it is an input into the destination, if I'm not mistaken, since it wouldn't be a valid data type matching the destination column.

Oracle NUMBER isn't quite the same as an INT as well. Please check this guide to see if you do not have to add a step in the package to do a data type conversion task between SQL Server and Oracle. 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b14270/apa.htm

Hope one of these two things help you fix your issue..

Comment: The "select *" was in the Oracle (destination) query, and SSIS is apparently happy with it. I agree that it seems odd. The NUMBER vs INT business crossed my mind as well, but NUMBER is receiving INT values so I decided that would be OK (int essentially being a subset); SSIS apparently agrees. Thanks anyway :)